# Replace an exact substring in column value

Tags: python, pandas

The 'Last year (2019)' should be replaced with 'LY'
I tried this but it did not work.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Revenue':["Last year (2019),This year (2020)","This year",np.nan],
           'Cost':["This year,Last Year","This year",np.nan]})
df1.iloc[:,0:3].replace(to_replace ='Last year (2019)', value = 'LY', regex = True)
```

[image]

I have tried several regex attempts using '\b' but nothing seems to work.
Any help is apprecciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help you here, you need to escape `(` and `)` to make it treat like as a literal character.

```
df1.iloc[:,0:3].replace(to_replace ='Last year \(2019\)', value = 'LY', regex = True)
```

Following is the testing of above code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Revenue':["Last year (2019),This year (2020)","This year",np.nan],
           'Cost':["This year,Last Year","This year",np.nan]})
df1.iloc[:,0:3].replace(to_replace ='Last year \(2019\)', value = 'LY', regex = True)


    Cost                Revenue
0   This year,Last Year LY,This year (2020)
1   This year           This year
2   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using regex, you have to escape the parenthesis, otherwise it will not work.

Also, you should set the `inplace` argument to `True` so that your object is updated. Otherwise, it will not change your current DataFrame but return an updated one.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Revenue': ["Last year (2019),This year (2020)", "This year", np.nan], 'Cost': ["This year,Last Year", "This year", np.nan]})
df1.replace(r'Last year \(2019\)', 'LY', inplace=True, regex=True)

print(df1)
```

Output

```
               Revenue                 Cost
0  LY,This year (2020)  This year,Last Year
1            This year            This year
2                  NaN                  NaN
```